# array_shift causing me to lose elements in an array stored in $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session, smarty, pear

**UPDATE** - I did not find the problem. I'm assuming that the person who deleted their comments was right and either Asset.php or array_shift() was being called twice. What I did find was a sweet spot in another file that handled the form object and allowed me to manipulate the array as I intended without deleting extra elements. Left this up in case anyone wants to browse through it.

---

I have a website run by a Controller.php that shows different pages according to a GET value run through a switch. The relevant case is:

```
case 'pgImportAsset': {
  require_once FORMS_DIR.'/Asset.php';

  $form = new ImportAssetForm(&$smarty, &$req);

  if(!empty($_SESSION['list'])){
    $form->processTo(&$smarty, array('pg'=>   'pgImportAsset'));
  } else {
    $form->processTo(&$smarty, array('pg'=> 'pgListClip'));
  }
  break;
}
```

The $_SESSION['list'] variable is an array that stores strings of file names that come from a java applet that uploads those files. The array gets initialized perfectly to something like

```
Array
(
  [0] => 0.jpg
  [1] => 1.jpg
  [2] => 2.jpg
  [3] => 3.jpg
  [4] => 4.jpg
)
```

and so on. Here's where it gets weird. The one line where the array gets decremented is in Asset.php

```
$this->filename=array_shift($_SESSION['list']);
```

The array will go into the instance of that page and I'll have a print_r statement right before and right after that line. Even though the array goes in with ***all 5*** elements in it, the two print statements will show.

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1.jpg
  [1] => 2.jpg
  [2] => 3.jpg
  [3] => 4.jpg
)
Array
(
  [0] => 2.jpg
  [1] => 3.jpg
  [2] => 4.jpg
)
```

It gets weirder. Shortly after that line in Asset.php I have this line (I'm using smarty).

```
$smarty->assign('filename',$this->filename);
```

And that shows up as the first element, which in this case would be 0.jpg. The value $this->filename then gets sent to a database without any lines of code altering it. What ends up stored in the database is 1.jpg.

I am completely lost and confused. Please help.

More information on it, Asset.php uses an object called ImportAssetForm that expands on the QuickForm library in PEAR as well as a couple other libraries including DB and some others.

This is not my code originally, I've just been tasked with changing it. The PEAR libraries are probably dated a little bit, but I don't have the knowledge of PEAR to go in and completely revamp the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was the script reloading due to an error check in my code. Since I didn't want to disrupt that, I moved the handling of the array to another location that did not execute twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems in working with session for many years ;)

try what's this guy says here: [PHP Session data not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved/6777970#6777970)

> I dont know what this internally means, i just explain it to myself
>   that the session variable change was not quick enough :)