# My session works in local mode but not in server

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have this PHP code, which is a simply login system.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Connecting to DB

    mysql_connect("localhost", "database1", "dbdb1");
    mysql_select_db("dbdb");

    // Getting session info and params AFTER sending POST params

    print_r($_SESSION);

    function doLogin($username_post, $password_post){
        $select_login = "
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username 
              FROM 
                users 
            WHERE 
                username = '$username_post'
                password = '$password_post'
            LIMIT 1";

        $query_login = mysql_query($select_login);
        $rows_login = mysql_num_rows($query_login);

        $array  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_login);

        if($rows_login>0){

            $_SESSION['user_in'] = True;

            return True;

        }else{
            return False;
        }
    }

    // LOGIN

    $username           = $_POST['username'];                                       
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
        doLogin($username, $password);
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action = "" method = "post">
                <input type = "text" name = "username"/>
                <input type = "password" name = "password" />

                <button type="submit" name = "submit">Login</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Appearently, it works. This code works great in local mode, but when I execute on server mode, I have a serious problem, it simply doesn't works. If you see, I put a print_r(); inside the code, I placed that, in order to know if session were succefully send. In local mode, I can see the sent params, just after reload. In server mode, I can't see it, it seems like session weren't sent.

Any suggestions? What is really happening with this code? I need to know why it works on local mode but not on server.

PHP SESSION:

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your DB server has the same DB with the same login and data as your local machine?

if no rows are returned from the DB, it won't set the session value

Comment: Yes, it does. Same database. It logs well, but doesn't store the session.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your server does not support sessions. check with `phpinfo()` command and check if  `session support` parameter is enabled and if it is enabled, check other session parameters with your server admin

Edit 1: You should use `AND` between where conditions

```
$select_login = "
    SELECT 
        id, 
        username 
      FROM 
        users 
    WHERE 
        username = '$username_post' AND
        password = '$password_post'
    LIMIT 1";
```