# php session is not stored in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I have not worked with php for some time and came back to one of my projects just to find out that the session variable is not stored. It came like a surprise, because the last time I checked, it worked and I have not used php (therefore has not changed the code or config).

The situation is as follows: session is not stored across the pages (I can save it and it shows the same on the page, but when I refresh - nothing changes).

I looked here [PHP Session data not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved) and replicated the example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
else
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;

echo "views = ". $_SESSION['views'];
echo '<p><a href="page1.php">Refresh</a></p>';
```

but nothing changes: I still has views = 1.

Nevertheless I have not changed my config, but I still looked at phpinfo():
[image]

I checked my permissions to write to the folder /tmp - they are ok, moreover after each refresh a new file appears there.

Then I checked the work in other browsers: and to my surprise it works in firefox: the number correctly increases there.

So the situation: in chrome it does not work, in firefox it works. I use chrome as default. I also remember playing with chrome options when it switches to blink, but as far as I remember I changed back everything.

Any idea how I can fix php sessions in chrome?

P.S:

- cookies are enabled in chrome
- sessions files are in /tmp I tried to delete them all and when later I refresh the page in chrome - the new file appears
- in headers I am sending Cookie:PHPSESSID=mystring but no session id

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Chromium. [Issue 114877](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114977)

Place a favicon in the root folder, and this should correct your issue.

Comment: yes. unfortunately if you add favicon, you and your users have to visit website for favicon update. chrome history cannot resolve the new favicon from extension.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on cookies and exit incognito (private browsing) in Chrome.

**edit:** try setting session.cache_expire back to 180 (the default)

Comment: @SalvadorDali Uhm, looking at your phpinfo... Should your session_cache_expire be 0 ?! Try putting it back to 180 (the default). You can try doing it in code, without editing php.ini , by placing `session_cache_expire(180);` **before** `session_start();`. The manual specified no default behaviour for setting session.cache_expire to 0, so it might really mean 0 minutes.

Comment: @SalvadorDali But just to doublecheck: FireFox and IE do work ? And in the developer tools you see the page being loaded and getting a 200 - OK ? (Not that it is being served from the cache.)

Answer (score 0):

I used to come upon some border cases while using php sessions with different browsers.

Can you confirm that the code example is working if using [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) right before the `echo` statements?

Also you should consider holding your session into another storage rather than the default - in files at the tmp folder. Memcache, redis, database are all options which would scale great.

Comment: but the default should work, and to change to other storage just because this isn't working is a bit awkward...

Comment: I've mentioned a consideration based on my experience with using sessions. I think there is no experienced php developer who would prefer to save its sessions into the default tmp folder.

Comment: Note that this is just an advice - it won't fix the issue he complains about. The solution I gave is to try ```session_write_close()```.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment `session.save_path = "/tmp"` directive in `php.ini` using prefix `;` .

So after restart `apache`, `phpinfo()` should be show `no value` for `session_save_path`

Comment: How's that a fix for the question: ```Any idea how I can fix php sessions in chrome?```

Comment: cokies send by the PHP server to the browser and it saves in `session.save_path`, but perhaps your browser `chrome` have not access to the path

Comment: The `save_path` relates to where the PHP stores the physical file for the session on the server. No browser will have access to that path.

Comment: @PeerBr,  cookie (contain session_id) stores in client side and session data stores in server side at `session.save_path`. it is better to not change this path.

Answer (score 0):

Please check session use cookie in php.ini. If it is zero activate it to 1 like
session.use_cookies = 1

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it was, removing the www from the domain name here:

```
session_set_cookie_params([
  'lifetime' => (365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
  'path' => '/',
  'domain' => 'demo.com',
  'secure' => true,
  'httponly' => true,
  'samesite' => 'Strict',
]);
```

after that it works