# PHP $_SESSION Values Don't Persist Between Requests

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have you files:

**set.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = "anglinb";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

I have one server where I can go to set.php and then go to get.php and both pages will show the same result of vardump.

The second server, hosted by namecheap, will not store the data. The $_SESSION superglobal was working fine but suddenly it stopped working.

**What I have tired**

I have check the writablity of the tmp domain suggested here [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved). However the information still doesn't persist between requests. I know my browser settings and my code is ok because it works on my server.

I have tried to set the path to a different directory where the permissions are 777.

```
ini_set(' session.save_path','/tmpp');
```

I can post the phpinfo page if this would help.

Here are the two cookies:
set:
[image: set cookie]

get:
[image: get cookie]

Comment: Enable error_reporting. Do the session cookie ids stay the same?

Comment: How should see if the cookie ids stay the same? I have error_reporting turned on.

Comment: Browser, right click, site properties, cookie manager.

Comment: Ok I did that and posted the images in the question. You can a take a look at the site if you want: dev.briananglin.me/set.php

Comment: That's not a PHP session cookie. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` atop the script.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to turn output buffering on.

Comment: Read here why that's an unreliable workaround: [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)