# Language problems (Cookie/Session)

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, multilingual

I have problem with language on my page. When i choose one language it take it corectly, all content change, but when i reload or go to another page the language change back to default language, something with cookies are not corect :/. On localhost all works good but on hosting dont work.

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    session_set_cookie_params('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
    $lang = 'lv';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'lv':
      $lang_file = 'lv.php';
      break;
  case 'ru':
      $lang_file = 'ru.php';
      break;
  default:
      $lang_file = 'lv.php';
}

include_once 'lang/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you've uploaded everything correctly? Is the ru.php on the server up to date?

Comment: Are you setting the language each time you hit the page?  You're getting the language from the URL I assume?  Perhaps post the URL you're testing with?  

Another possibility is your host doesn't allow you to mess with the $_SESSION are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, i uploaded all corectly.

Comment: @mam8cc No, i dont get any errors :/, i set the language and its saves on localhost, and i can go to all my pages, but on hosting they just drop language to default.

Comment: Could you please post the URL you are using to test?  

i.e. http://localhost:8000/?foo=bar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the answers here:

[PHP Session data not being saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved)

Code that you showed us works well, so it must be a server/configuration issue. Good luck :)

Comment: I got that what i want. I add this at my links ?lang=<?php echo $_SESSION['lang']; ?> all works good, thanx for all :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `session_set_cookie_params` and not `setcookie`?

Adding the `?lang` parameter on *every* link is going to be tiresome. And bloat your code and make it less readable.