# PHP Sessions not keeping values

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my PHP (version 5.6) session. They are not being kept between pages, or even when I refresh my page.

On top of all my files I have :

```
<?php
session_start();
```

(there is no space or anything before).

When the user click on link, it's calling a function to set the website language to English or French. After some verification on the $_GET["lang"] value, I create the session like that :

```
$_SESSION["lang"] = $_GET["lang"];
```

If I do

```
var_dump($_SESSION["lang"]);
```

the server return string(2) "fr" or string(2) "en" regarding to which language the user select. Until there, everything is working great ;)

Problem is if I refresh the page, or go to another one, and try to return the session value, it's always NULL...

I know i could user other ways to translate the website, but I need the sessions to work for other functionality of my application (login, ...)

Because it was working few days ago, I first supposed it was a changed on the server, so I've contact my server administrator, but they told me they didn't change anything.
I have the PHP error reporting set to E_ALL but no errors are displayed...

If someone could help me with that, it would be great, i'm stuck on this bug since 3 days now ^^.

Thanks !

EDIT :

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION["lang"]);
if(!isset($_SESSION["lang"]) || $_SESSION["lang"] == null){
    $_SESSION["lang"] = "fr";
}
if(isset($_GET["lang"]) && ($_GET["lang"] == "fr" || $_GET["lang"] == "en")){
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $_GET["lang"];
}
var_dump($_SESSION["lang"]);
```

Comment: Put `echo session_id();` after `session_start()`. If you try to refresh the page, this value changes?

Comment: Check if you change or unset the `SESSION` in the top of your page or somewhere else

Comment: Yes it does change on every refresh

@SulthanAllaudeen I already check that but no i don't, I only unset my session on the logout page, which is never called on this part of the website

Comment: See if you write `session_start` in one php file then either include it in other php files(that is not good). Or in every php file write `session_start` at top. One more problem may occurring which is  pointed by @Leggendario

Comment: Then your problem is that a new and empty session start every time.

Comment: I wonder, If session is started twice then it forgets the old sessions' value ? That is not the exact reason

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Session data not being saved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved)

Comment: @ThibaudLacan : Can you `var_dump($_SESSION);
` in both pages ?

Comment: My application is setting the session to "fr" if the session["lang"] doesn't exist.
So first time you hit the website, var_dump($_SESSION) return :
array(1) {
  ["lang"]=>
  string(2) "fr"
}
Then if i go to the link to set language to English, it return :
array(1) {
  ["lang"]=>
  string(2) "en"
}
If i go back to home page, or refresh the page, I get french back

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing @SulthanAllaudeen, but i'm checking everything and have only a session_start on top of everything (i include my files on a index.php regarding to the url the guy is trying to access)

Comment: Your browser accept cookies? `var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());` what do you get?

Comment: you need to provide more code.

Comment: @Leggendario i get : 
array(5) {
  ["lifetime"]=&gt;
  int(0)
  ["path"]=&gt;
  string(1) "/"
  ["domain"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["secure"]=&gt;
  bool(false)
  ["httponly"]=&gt;
  bool(false)
}

Comment: @ThibaudLacan  Can you Close all your browser and try it in a incognito or private mode from your browser. Make sure you not run the same page in other tab :)

Comment: Yep i'm working in incognito right now, I have a  friend trying on his laptop next to me and another one testing from another location ;)

Comment: @ThibaudLacan Are you connected to lan to do it ? And now you able to get it ?

Comment: Yes my website is online already, i'm not working on local

Comment: After incognito it didn't worked ?

Comment: No still not working. Us 3 are trying on different browser (chrome, firefox and IE) incognito mode and cookies enable ....
I check my session_save_path as well and it's a writable path

Comment: "When the user click on link, it's calling a function to set the website language to English or French. " Have you posted the function. Let's see that.

Comment: My mistake @timgavin it's not a function, i'm checking the $_GET["lang"] and assign it to the session when page load. You can see the code at the bottom of my post

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I found why : i needed to encode my index.php file in UTF-8 without BOM, it was encoded in UTF-8 only.
Can't really explain why but at least it's fixed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it !
My index.php file was encoded in UTF-8, i changed it to UTF-8 without BOM and it worked !
Really weird bug, I hope it will help someone ;)

Comment: next time enables the display of the errors! if you did that you would have noticed that session_start  throw a warning

Comment: My error are displayed.
It didn't return any warning, the session_start() was initiating each time that's why my session_id was never the same

Answer (score 2):

from the limited code you're providing, my guess is that the `$_GET` argument isn't always set, which would then set the session to null.

try this...

```
if(isset($_GET["lang"])) {
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $_GET["lang"];
} else {
    echo 'lang not set';
}
```

---

EDIT: OP provided additional code.

This will return 'fr' if no value, or if an acceptable value hasn't been provided in the URL arguments. it's similar to what you have, however, I've wrapped the argument check in parentheses to make it a little tighter and changed the order. Your code was returning 'en' if nothing was provided.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['lang']) && ($_GET['lang'] == 'fr' || $_GET['lang'] == 'en')) {
    if($_GET['lang'] == 'fr') {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';
    }
    elseif($_GET['lang'] == 'en') {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';
}

var_dump($_SESSION['lang']);
```