# PHP $_SESSION var cannot saved in mobile

Tags: php, session

I'm develop a hybrid application and it will using PHP sessions to save user information. In my case, I tried to used php sessions to save the data, but it doesn't save. And then, to testing in web, the result var is show saved.

Here is my example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["Token"])){
    $token = $_POST["Token"];

    if (isset($_SESSION['device_token']) && $_SESSION['device_token']) {
        $token = $_SESSION['device_token'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['device_token'] = "notoken";
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my PHP info:

[My php Info 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky2ak.png)

[My php Info 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7THbL.png)

Edit:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.save_path',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/phpVar');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["Token"])){
$token = $_POST["Token"];
$_SESSION['device_token'] = $token;
}
if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
$token = $_SESSION['device_token'];
$member_id = $_GET['ID'];
$_SESSION['ID'] = $member_id;

echo $_SESSION['device_token'] ;
echo $_SESSION['ID'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved?rq=1) help you.

Answer (score 0):

because you missed the }

so, instead of:

```
if(isset($_POST["Token"])){
    $token = $_POST["Token"];
```

should be:

```
if(isset($_POST["Token"])){
    $token = $_POST["Token"];
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, then try to see whether you session directory is writable:

```
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo "No, it's not. Path:".session_save_path(); 
}
else{
    echo "yes, it's writable";
}
```

**EDIT**

when path is not set, you might set it manually just before session_start

```
ini_set('session.save_path',getcwd(). '/tmp');
```

and afterwards you need to create tmp folder and give it right permission

Comment: Thank for your help!  HAHA, because it is not copy from my source.. maybe have some missing~

Comment: i can see the session in folder(tmp), but i can't get the var

Comment: how do you mean "i can't get the var"? What's the result of echo $_SESSION['device_token']?

Comment: the mean is cannot  get the session var to use. echo $_SESSION['device_token'] is print noting

Comment: can you re-post all your code, to see how it looks?

Comment: Ok, posted.  When i finished the post method, the next step is loading get method. but i can't in get method to use session token.

Comment: you are making it complicate now. Let's first see whether sessions work by you or not. Remove everything and write only ini_set('session.save_path',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/phpVar'); session_start();$_SESSION['te'] = 12;echo $_SESSION['te'];