# Why my PHP session did not update when I refresh my page?

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['tt'])) {
    echo 'delete session' . $_SESSION['tt'];
    unset($_SESSION['tt']);
    return;
} else {
    echo 'save session';
    $_SESSION['tt'] = '123456';
    return;
}
?>
```

when I refresh this page, always echo 'save session', 
then I delete `unset($_SESSION['tt'])`, refresh, always echo 'delete session'
but I undo delete , refresh , still echo 'delete session'.

I need echo 'save……' and 'delete……' in turn when I refresh many times, it not work.
please help!

Comment: remove `return` and try

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @yangwenqian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Session data not being saved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved)

Answer (score 0):

Set session.auto_start variable to 1 in php.ini file, some instalation don't load session by default

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @dloal