# PHP Sessions not working in different server

Tags: session, server, php

Hi I have a basic session code for testing which I have uploaded to two different servers.

**File1 -**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**File2 -**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

we can access the session information we set on the first page.

**Links for Server 1 :**

http://thycart.in/adaptyapp/1.php

http://thycart.in/adaptyapp/2.php

**Links for Server 2 :**(not working)

http://103.231.209.162:60070/1.php

http://103.231.209.162:60070/2.php

**PHP Info Server 1:**
http://thycart.in/adaptyapp/phpinfo.php

**PHP Info Server 2:**
http://103.231.209.162:60070/phpinfo.php

For some reason the session is not working in one server.Please help to find the reason.Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this may solve your query .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
 if(isset($_SESSION)) {


 echo "Favorite color is " .$_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
 echo "Favorite animal is " .$_SESSION["favanimal"]. ".";
  }

 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```