# Session data not saving

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am debugging a php session that worked when I last tested it, a couple of months ago. The code has not changed in any way, but the session has now stopped working.

I have read multiple questions here as well as other articles but no suggestions have solved this problem. I believe my code is correct, but when I asked support at Bluehost, they say it must be a code problem:

I am starting a session and setting a few session variables:

```
<?php
    session_start();

$_SESSION["franchise_name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["db_name"] = $_POST["name"];
$_SESSION["franchise_location"] = $_POST["franchise_location"];
$_SESSION["franchise_phone"] = $_POST["franchise_phone"];
$_SESSION["franchise_address"] = $_POST["franchise_address"];
$_SESSION["franchise_email"] = $_POST["franchise_email"];

header("Location: session.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit;

?>
```

If I echo the session variables immediately after setting them, all is well. Good stuff. So I know everything works in this section.

session.php looks like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
echo 'Testing Output:';
echo session_status();
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
phpinfo();
?>
```

So when I test this, no data is being passed in the session. The output on session.php is:

```
Testing Output:2
array(0) {
}
```

I also set up a tester to see if session data is enabled:

```
<?php
// Start Session
session_start();
// Show banner
echo '<b>Session Support Checker</b><hr />';
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!<br />'; 
} else {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is writable for PHP!<br />'; 

}
// Check if the page has been reloaded
if(!isset($_GET['reload']) OR $_GET['reload'] != 'true') {
   // Set the message
   $_SESSION['MESSAGE'] = 'Session support enabled!<br />';
   // Give user link to check
   echo '<a href="?reload=true">Click HERE</a> to check for PHP Session Support.<br />';
} else {
   // Check if the message has been carried on in the reload
   if(isset($_SESSION['MESSAGE'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['MESSAGE'];
   } else {
      echo 'Sorry, it appears session support is not enabled, or you PHP version is to old. <a href="?reload=false">Click HERE</a> to go back.<br />';
   }
}
?>
```

The result of this test shows that the session data didn't work here either and that the session path is indeed writable. Phpinfo shows that sessions are enabled.

Is there anything else I can try to help me troubleshoot this issue? Thanks.

Update: I did try seeting the session path with 
    ini_set(' session.save_path','SOME WRITABLE PATH');
but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Note: I copied these exact files from bluehost to hostgator and they work fine there. So it seems to be hosting related, but bluehost says it's my problem to fix. Not sure what to ask them to do.

Comment: Maybe do you have some other request? In a particular case I had a 404 page that was starting a session. In my site there wasn't a favicon, my browser was requesting it and two requests were arriving to the server having an unpredicted behaviour.

Comment: All of the code is listed above - so I don't think so?

Comment: ok. I have tested your code in my local server and it seems its working over here.

Comment: It must be a problem at bluehost but their tech support isn't very supportive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Session data not being saved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155920/php-session-data-not-being-saved)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The answer to that question did not solve my problem.

Comment: `!= 'true'` is in quotes (is a string) and is not a boolean `TRUE` as per `?reload=true` - try removing the quotes `!=true` @WilliamAlexander

Comment: In session.php - try to use conditional statements to check if a session is set and not empty @WilliamAlexander rather than just a var_dump.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I think that the conditional there is actually checking for a string not a boolean. I tried your suggestion anyway, and it still gave the same result.

Comment: I added the following conditional:`if($_SESSION){
echo 'Session!<br />';
} else {
echo 'No Session!<br />';
}` and it still appears there is no session.

Answer (score 0):

from php [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) page:

> **Note**:
>   To use cookie-based sessions, `session_start()` must be called **before** outputing anything to the browser.

remove the spaces before `session_start()`, they are considered output.

---

**Update:**

It can also be related to the location of the session files, you may try setting a new location:

```
ini_set('session.save_path','/some/safe/path/to/sessions');
session_start();
```

Make sure `sessions` has the appropriate permissions

Comment: Thank you for the Update Pedro - I should have noted in my initial post that I did try changing the session path as one of my earlier troubleshooting tests.

Comment: Have you tried outputting `$_POST` content without redirection? Is there any content ? does it show any errors ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the last comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631033/sessions-not-working-on-my-blue-host-server

Comment: Thank you - I had seen that but was certain the files were without BOM - nevertheless I resaved the files to be sure, still the problem persists.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't know how to help you further!

Answer (score 0):

I called Blue Host - this second support person was more alert than the first and recognized that Varnish Caching could cause the problem. We disabled it and voila! Fixed.